# How to set Hibernate naming strategy in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA and use multiple database, so I must configure it myself instead of using `@HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`.

```
public class TesterDbConfig {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;


    @Bean
    public JpaProperties testerJpaProperties() {
        JpaProperties jpaProperties = new JpaProperties();
        return jpaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
    public DataSource testerDataSource() {
        return (DataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().type(DataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean testerEntityManager(
        JpaProperties testerJpaProperties) {
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(testerJpaProperties);
        return builder.dataSource(testerDataSource()).packages(Cabang.class).persistenceUnit("primary")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager testerTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory testerEntityManager) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(testerEntityManager);
    }

    private EntityManagerFactoryBuilder createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(
        JpaProperties testerJpaProperties) {
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = createJpaVendorAdapter(testerJpaProperties);
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(jpaVendorAdapter, testerJpaProperties,
            this.persistenceUnitManager);
    }

    private JpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter(JpaProperties testerJpaProperties) {
        AbstractJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(testerJpaProperties.isShowSql());
        adapter.setDatabase(testerJpaProperties.getDatabase());
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform(testerJpaProperties.getDatabasePlatform());
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(testerJpaProperties.isGenerateDdl());
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

With this, every time I create a model, I must use `@Column` in every variable because in my database, I use snake case, but in model class, I use camel case.

How can I set the Hibernate naming strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it via `JpaProperties`, which you already use in your configuration:

```
@Bean
public JpaProperties testerJpaProperties() {
    JpaProperties jpaProperties = new JpaProperties();
    JpaProperties.Hibernate hibernate = new JpaProperties.Hibernate();
    hibernate.setNamingStrategy(SpringNamingStrategy.class);
    jpaProperties.setHibernate(hibernate);
    return jpaProperties;
}
```

And add

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean testerEntityManager(
    JpaProperties testerJpaProperties) {
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(testerJpaProperties);
    return builder.dataSource(testerDataSource())
        .packages(Cabang.class)
        .persistenceUnit("primary")
        .properties(Collections.singletonMap("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",testerJpaProperties.getHibernate().getNamingStrategy()))
        .build();
}
```

Comment: it still give error
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column ... does not exist because maybe it's not converting to snake case. Wrong naming strategy? or implementation?

Comment: Look like besides setting in JpaProperties, I must add it also in LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

`.properties(Collections.singletonMap("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",testerJpaProperties.getHibernate().getNamingStrategy()))`

I get it from example in [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3654)

Thanks for the method for setting it btw @Bohuslav